# Save face color in .obj file

Tags: mesh

I have an `.obj` file storing triangle mesh. I wish to record a color for each of the triangle faces. Is there a way to save this information into `.obj` file so that software like MeshLab could identify and visualize it?

Answer (score 1):

It's way too late to help you but since I came across the same problem, someone might have the same problem later.

**Here is how I would do it :**

As you can read on [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) about .obj file format,

> Some applications support vertex colors, by putting red, green and blue values after x y and z (this precludes specifying w). The color values range from 0 to 1.

This method is now widely supported. I figured out that giving vertices the proper colors, will make most software (including MeshLab) automatically color the faces with those. This is advantageous when you want to store everything in an OBJ file.

```
v 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
v 0.0 0.5 0.5 1.0 0.0 0.0
v 0.5 0.5 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
f 3//3 2//2 1//1
```

Will make a red triangle.

Obviously, it will look way better if you use a [MTL file](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/mtl/mtl.html). But this is quick to make and useful for testing your code when you do 3D scan. Also I did not try this with indexed vertices, so it might not work the same way.